# Array of images that have to be placed in one horizontal line (with scrolling)

Tags: html, css

I just designed a portfolio website. I have a whole array of images that I want to keep in one line (with horizontal scroll). This only happens when I have set a fixed width for the surrounding div (in this case with class '.post-images'), wide enough to contain all images. This could be just fine if the amount of images and their widths wasn't dynamic. Unfortunately this isn't the case here. I want this div to be wrapping around all images and not causing them to float. I have tried to set the div's where I put each image in ('.post-image') to 'white-space: nowrap' to no avail.

See an example here: [Link](http://www.jolienholthuis.nl/wp/ballonartiest-micha-de-haan/)

How can I fix this problem? I hope someone is willing to give me a hand here ;)

Thanks,

Jeroen

Comment: I think you should ask this on doctype.com instead. This site is strictly about programming, not about web design. (JavaScript programming is relevant though)

Comment: Didn't knew this... I see a lot of css related issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the css for `.post_images` and `.post_image` with:

```
.post_images { white-space:nowrap; }
.post_image { display:inline; }
```

Effectively, this makes the wrapping `<div class="post_image">` elements redundant (that's the `display:inline`); you may as well remove them.

In general, most elements size their width according to that of their *container*; if you wish an element to size according to content, you'll need a `<table>`, `display: table` or single line.

***Edit:***  both [`white-space:nowrap`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) and [`display:inline`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) have been supported on all major browsers for years (in IE, all the way back to IE 5.5).

Comment: display:inline doesn't seem to work in IE, but display:table-cell does, although you then need to add padding to the images and sort out the margin/padding on the far right of the scroll box.

Comment: You must have made a typo or something; these css declarations have been supported for ages...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This will not solve my problem though. I tried changing the css like Eamon said to no avail. Inline style won't cause a horizontal scroll in its container (div with class '.post-content single'.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I removed the float: left at .post_image. Now it will work. Thanks a lot Eamon Nerbonne. Problem solved.